# Youtube gdata API returning limited results

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'm trying to retrieve the videos returned by the following youtube url using gdata API.

**https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lyndapodcast/uploads?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1&q=autodesk**

If I use the above url, I'm only getting first 4 results, whereas I can see this query produces more results.

**https://www.youtube.com/user/lyndapodcast/search?query=autodesk**

Is there a different way of constructing this url? I'm using standard gdata java API.

```
    String feedUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lyndapodcast/uploads?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1&q=autodesk";
    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("Test_App");
    Query query = new Query(new URL(feedUrl));
    VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(query, VideoFeed.class);
    for(VideoEntry videoEntry : videoFeed.getEntries() ) {
              ....
    }
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following URL displays 50 results for me:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lyndapodcast/uploads?v=2&max-results=50&start-index=1&query=autodesk